# Error Creating ExtensionProperties with Microsoft Graph

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

Problems with Microsoft Graph. This creates new ExtensionProperties according to [this documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/application_post_extensionproperties)

```
function crear($objeto, $datos){ 
    $graph->setApiVersion("beta");
    $r = $graph->createRequest("POST", "/$objeto")
        ->attachBody($datos)            
        ->execute();
}      

crear('applications/'.ID_APP.'/extensionProperties', array(
            'extensionProperty'=>array(
                "appDisplayName"=>NOMBRE_APP,
                "name"=>"cargo",
                "dataType"=>"Integer",
                "isSyncedFromOnPremises"=>true,
                "targetObjects"=>array('Group')
            )
        ));
```

Error:

```
Type: GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException

Message: Client error: `POST 
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/my_id_app/extensionProperties` resulted in a `405 Method Not Allowed` 
response: { "error": { "code": "Request_BadRequest", "message": "Specified 
HTTP method is not allowed for the request (truncated...)

Filename: /var/www/html/ischooldesarrollo/application/libraries/msgraph-sdk-
php/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php

Line Number: 111
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to create a schema extension definition please follow this documentation: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_overview

The link you have here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/application_post_extensionproperties should be removed from the documentation.  This alludes to the ability of creating Azure AD (Graph) directory schema extensions (a precursor to the version in Microsoft Graph).  Creating this type of extension definition is **not** supported in Microsoft Graph.  I will file an internal doc bug for this.

Hope this helps,